# Can dygraphs plot chart base on a subset of fields from a csv file?

Tags: graph, dygraphs

I would like to plot a chart base only on a subset of the fields from a csv file.  Can dygraphs do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`visibility`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#visibility) option to suppress display of particular columns in your data. That requires these columns to still be numeric & parse, of course. If you can't guarantee that, you'll need to preprocess your data.